Rsyslog ruleset filter based on matching a source IP list instead of a chain of "or" operators
I have a syslog server receiving different kinds of logs from multiple clients, either through a dedicated port or through UDP 514. When received, logs are written to a directory dedicated for a certain log type, which is determined either by the dedicated port or, if sent through UDP514, by the source IP. The .conf file structure is the following:
module(load="imudp")

template(name="logtype1" type="string" string="/path/to/var/log/logtype1/%fromhost%/%fromhost%.log")
template(name="logtype2" type="string" string="/path/to/var/log/logtype2/%fromhost%/%fromhost%.log")
#...more similar templates for each log type

ruleset(name="logtype1") {
    action(... dynafile="logtype1")
}
#...other rulesets for logs sent through dedicated port

ruleset(name="general") {
    if ($fromhost-ip=='<IP1>') or ($fromhost-ip=='<IP2>') 
        then {
            action(... dynafile="logtype2")
        }
    else if ($fromhost-ip=='<IP3>') or ($fromhost-ip=='<IP4>') or ($fromhost-ip=='<IP5>') or ($fromhost-ip=='<IP6>') #...or 20 more explicit IPs
        then {
            action(... dynafile="logtype3")
        }
    #...other else-if clauses   
}

input(type="imudp" port="<DEDICATED_PORT>" ruleset="logtype1")
#...other inputs for dedicated ports
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="general")

Is there any better way to write the ruleset general? I'm fine with this method if it's a few IPs per log type, but I want to avoid the long else-if clauses that contain 10+ addresses. E.g. by instead somehow implementing the logic "if fromhost-ip matches any value from the IP list in firewall_srcip.txt, write logs to a path defined in template3".

You might want to use RainerScript tables.
You have to provide a file, say mytable.json holding a json formatted table with the needed keys and values, for example:
{ "version" : 1,
  "nomatch" : "unknown",
  "type"    : "string",
  "table" : [
    {"index" : "172.1.4.2",   "value" : "A" },
    {"index" : "127.0.0.5",   "value" : "A" },
    {"index" : "104.18.39.38","value" : "B" },
  ]}

Obviously, it would be best to generate this with a small awk script from a more editable list of addresses and categories.
You load this table in the config file using lookup_table(). Then simply provide a single generic template using a variable $.myclass instead of all the multitude of log types, and set that variable by a lookup() from the table.
For example,
lookup_table(name="myipmap" file="mytable.json" reloadOnHUP="on")
template(name="all" type="string" string="/var/log/%$.myclass%/%fromhost-ip%.log")
set $.myclass = lookup("myipmap", $fromhost-ip);
action(type="omfile" dynaFile="all")

Note the semi-colon (;) at the end of the set command.
